# Can't add action to buttons in Visual Studio C++ using Windows Forms

Tags: visual-studio-2010, struct, c++-cli

Hello Dear Community of SO!
I have a following problem - I wrote a simple add_record function using structures (here is my main file):

```
// Exercise1.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"

using namespace Exercise1;

typedef struct student {
        char *name;
        int index;
        double avg;
        student *next;
        student *prev;
} stud;

student *first = 0;

[STAThreadAttribute]


void add_record(student **first, char *name, int index, double avg){
                student *new_stud = new student;
                if (*first!=0) (*first)->prev = new_stud;
                new_stud->name = name;
                new_stud->avg = avg;
                new_stud->index = index;
                new_stud->next = *first;
                new_stud->prev = 0;
                *first = new_stud;
}
```

However, I can't put this add record function into button action (with predefined data, just for testing purposes)
Code for `Form1.h`:

```
#pragma once

namespace Exercise1 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for Form1
    /// </summary>
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        Form1(void)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~Form1()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    protected: 
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
    //all remaining buttons here - irrelevant

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
}
 #pragma endregion
    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 String ^ i = "working";
                 textBox1->Text = i;

             }
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             String ^ g = "test";
             if(add_record(student **first, testname, 23, 3.5))
                 textBox1->Text = g;
         }

};
}
```

How to fix that part with record adding?
I get a following error:

```
1>d:\visual studio 2010 express\projects\exercise1\exercise1\Form1.h(176): error C2065: 'student' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\visual studio 2010 express\projects\exercise1\exercise1\Form1.h(176): error C2065: 'first' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\visual studio 2010 express\projects\exercise1\exercise1\Form1.h(176): error C2065: 'testname' : undeclared identifier
1>d:\visual studio 2010 express\projects\exercise1\exercise1\Form1.h(176): error C3861: 'add_record': identifier not found
```

I guess it's something connected with variable declaration but I don't know where to put that in order for it to work..

Thanks in advance

Comment: @AtoMerZ - seriously it wasn't me...I can't vote on my own questions

Comment: You will have to deal with the limitations of the C++ compiler, it is a one-pass compiler.  It must see a declaration before you can use the identifier in code.  This will require that you write the Form1 method definitions in a separate .cpp source code file.  Just keep the declaration of them in Form1.h, copy/paste the method bodies in, say, Form1.cpp

Comment: This isn't C++; this is C++/CLI. Updated tags accordingly

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippet.

There is no type defined as `student` - the struct is `typdef` to `stud` - this explains why the compiler yells at you it doesn't recognize the `student **first` argument type in the `add_record` method declaration.

```
using namespace Exercise1;

typedef struct student {
        char *name;
        int index;
        double avg;
        student *next;
        student *prev;
} stud; // <<<-------------------- should it be "} student;"?

student *first = 0;

[STAThreadAttribute]


void add_record(student **first, char *name, int index, double avg){
                student *new_stud = new student;
                if (*first!=0) (*first)->prev = new_stud;
                new_stud->name = name;
                new_stud->avg = avg;
...
```